# Multiple items in single query. How to separate them?

Tags: query, web

What I would like to do is exclude preferred names in a web query in single command. For example, now if I want to exclude some system accounts or user names that are named John and Edward and other I am putting a query like this: `{searchboxquery} contentclass=spspeople -e-mail: *.no  -accountname:-*Adm*  -*lync*   -PreferredName:"John*" -PreferredName:"Edward*"-PreferredName:"Gregor*" -PreferredName:"Joseph*" -PreferredName:"User*"` etc. etc. Everytime I need to add `-PreferredName` How to avoid this?

How to select multiple words to exclude just by separating them with comma or other separator? I tried `-PreferredName:"John*" , "Edward*" ,"Joseph*"` but it does not work.
Any help?

Comment: I am not sure why you reffering to powershell at all. Is a web query also a powershell command?. The query I am testing  is a webpart query text, available after edit Webpart, and change query option. I added more code in original question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.